# Не выводятся логи

Tags: java, логирование, log4j, slf4j

Не выводятся логи в stdout.

Использую для логирования `slf4j` и `log4j`.

Изначально, когда проект был не многомодульным, всё работало прекрасно. Но как только я сделал из него `maven multi-module` проект, тогда все логи перестали выводиться(кроме стандартного INFO уровня).

`slf4j` и `log4j` подключены в родительском `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>department-app</groupId>
  <artifactId>department-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>department</name>

  <modules>
    <module>rest</module>
    <module>web-app</module>
  </modules>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Настройка log4j:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Так же есть логирование в контроллере, но оно так же не работает:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeesController.class);
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/employee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<Employees> deleteEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        employeesService.delete(id);
        logger.info(id + "deleted successful");
        return employeesService.getAll();
    }
```

Comment: там spring-boot? Если так, то там нужно убрать из зависимостей spring-boot-logger, возможно он подсовывает свою версию log4j. А что при старте приложения пишет? должен ругаться если не находит файл конфигурации, если ничего такого нет, то нужно проверять настройки логгера.

Comment: нет, я не использую его

Comment: И как проверить эти настройки?

Comment: зачем вы юзаете два логера вместе? что это вообще за проект spring,jersey? мало информации я не могу вам дать сходу совет.

Comment: Это spring проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот Вам пример **log4j.properties** и **pom.xml**. Попробуйте сделать, как у меня в примере. Я тоже использую модули в своем проекте, у к-рых отдельные pom.xml. Пример моего ниже указанного **pom.xml** принадлежит модулю, а не основному проекту.
Пример **log4j.properties**, в к-ром указываются настройки, как для stdout, так и для лог файла:

```
#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CONSOLE, SYSLOG, FILE

log4j.logger.org.springframework.data.mongodb = ERROR
log4j.logger.путь.к.вашему.каталогу = DEBUG

#Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Syslog appender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG = org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost = localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}{UTC} %-5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility = LOCAL0

# Direct log messages to a log file
#log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/var/log/ваш_название/ваш_название.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}{UTC} %-5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

В **pom.xml** будут только те зависимости, к-рые нужны для **log4j**:

org.slf4j
        slf4j-api
        1.7.7

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```